# How can I obfuscate a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, string

Basically, I want to make a game in JavaScript and allow a user to get a copy paste-able code which stores their data. In reality, this "code" is actually obfuscated JSON that can be decoded by the application later.

I don't need much security, as I am aware that if people put some effort in they can view/modify the save, and I have no interest in stopping them. I just want the average user to not be tempted and/or see unnecessary information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you've obfuscated what you've tried so efficiently, that I couldn't find it from your question. Use that same powerful obfuscation in your app too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use base64 encoding to encode your json String. it would be faster approach.

If you with pure javascript :

```
var encodedData = btoa("stringToEncode");
```

If you are using nodejs:

base-64 encoding:

```
var encodedStr = new Buffer("Hello World").toString('base64')
```

decode to original value:

```
var originalString = new Buffer("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('utf-8')
```

Comment: OP did not say anything abut using Nodejs. So I'd just suggest `btoa()`.

Comment: OP could use Browserify if he really wanted it on the client

Comment: I am using it in the browser, no node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Well... given that there is no security concern and you only want users to see what appears to be garbled data you can "encode" all the json data

```
var jsonData = {"key":"value"};

// turn it into a string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

// replace some letters
var awkardString = jsonString.replace(/a/g, '!Ax6'); // be carefull, you should replace a letter with a pattern that does not already exist on the string.

// encode it with some type of reversible encoding
var garbledData = encodeURI(jsonString);

// output is: %7B%22key%22:%22v!Ax6lue%22%7D

// to "decode" it do the same steps in reverse
awkardString = decodeURI(garbledData);
jsonString = awkardString.replace(/!Ax6/g, 'a'); // now you see, if '!Ax6' existed on the source string, you would loose it and get an 'a' in return. That is why the replacement should be as unique as possible
jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```